# While making transaction from local server transaction not gets added

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, transactions, braintree

I have implemented Braintree API in .net core app.
While making a transaction from my local machine it is not get added in Braintree transaction section.
But from prod server transaction get added in Braintree transaction details section.
There is no error transaction is successful but I don't find any record of the transaction that I have done from a local machine.

Comment: can you put some code to begin with. are you using proper keys for the transaction?

Comment: Yes I am using same key ,everything is same on local and prod server even code is same only the difference is local server runs on http and prod is on https but I think thats not the issue

Comment: @RajanSharma thanks man I got the solution It was a key issue I forgot the change keys from my development setting.